# Would it be haram as a Sunni Muslim to ask Allah to give you a serious illness in your dua?

Tags: allah, sunni, dua, death

Not to ask for death but to ask for a serious illness that could potentially kill you e.g asking for a severe form of the coronavirus or cancer. Is it haram to ask for this in Dua?

Answer (score 0):

Allah will do what He wills. We may ask for help and healing. I t is not a sin to speak to Allah asking to let you die. Allah will do what He will do and we are to accept His will.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong to ask Allah to hurt yourself, but Allah will do what he wills. If there is a reason that you want something bad to happen to yourself, then you should discuss your problems with someone